# Mongodb : How to find out all the documents which are near certain location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geolocation

I have collection `shops` in mongodb with following important attributes

```
{  
  .......  
  address:{  
    ....  
    lat:15.9844,  
    lon:18:3333  
   }  
}
```

I also have a `person` collection with his latitude and longitude information.
I want to find out all the shops which are nearby that person (say distance between shop and person is less then 500 meters).

I am trying to write and query using nodejs. I wrote a function that takes two location and finds out distance between them. How can I go about writing the query?
Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 2):

change lat and lon to coordinates : [15.9844,18:3333]

```
db.shops.find(
       {
         address:
           { $near :
              {
                $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ] },
                $minDistance: 0,
                $maxDistance: 500
              }
           }
       }
    )
```